# How to remove website SSL exception message at client end

Tags: ssl, openssl

Guidance required to avoid SSL exception message at browser level when user access my site as like gmail or so.

My company has bought 228 bit certified SSL from verisign and checked clear status from http://certlogik.com/ssl-checker/

Comment: Presumably you mean 128 or 256 bits, not 228: this would typically be the shared key size. It has nothing to do with the certificate key size, although CAs documentations tend to be misleading on this point.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid browser warnings you should:

- Configure your server with a certificate that is issued by a CA trusted by most clients. There is no absolute list, since this can be configured, but there is a set of well-established CAs that are part of the CA bundling programmes from various OS/browsers (see [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11464/2435) for example). Verisign is usually one of them, so you should OK there.
- Make sure the your server host name (as it should be seen by the client) matches one of the names in that certificate. The details of the matching rules are in RFC 2818 (Section 3.1) and RFC 6125; in short, if your certificate has Subject Alternative Name DNS entries, the host name you're serving must be one of them, otherwise it should be in the `CN` of the Subject DN.
- Make sure you don't mix content when serving the pages: all the resources linked to in any way (images, scripts, CSS, iframes and Ajax requests) should all point to `https://` URIs (whether relative or absolute). If some of these resources are hosted on separate servers, their certificates must also be trusted by the client (same as two previous rules).